# Empy string key in enum causing column update when checking instance in conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, ruby-on-rails-5

*I am using Rails 5.0.0.1*

We wanted an empty string to be an option in the `enum` in one of our models. After several days running in production, finding something was wrong and debugging the problem, we found: an instance of that model was having its column updated everytime the code checked its truthiness (i.e. `!@model` and `!!@model`). This was caused by having a key-pair in the enum with the key being an empty string `{'': 0, 'good': 1}`.

The initial intention was to cast an empty string into nil `{'': nil, 'good':1}` (something is wrong in the API consumer that sends an empty string and we don't want to save that). After checking the problem, we realized **the nil value in the enum hash is not the problem, only the empty string in one of its keys**.

Now that we know the bug exists, we will find a workaround. However we want to know why was this happening as no error was raised on creating the model, checking its truthiness or elsewhere in the code.

I found [this similar bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26665), but it is about `validates_associated` and `Foo.create`, no explanation is given to the problem.

#### Steps to reproduce

Create a model with an integer column `rails g model Example my_enum:integer`

```
class CreateExamples < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :examples do |t|
      t.integer :my_enum

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Specify the `my_enum` column as an `enum` in the model:

```
class Example < ApplicationRecord
  enum my_enum: { '': 0, good: 1}
end
```

Create an instance of it with `my_enum = 'good'` and check its truthiness

```
@model = Example.new
@model.my_enum = 'good'
@model.save
@model.my_enum # => 'good'
# so far so good
# the model works as expected if restarting console,
# finding it with Example.first, and so on...

!@model # For some unknown reason updates my_enum to nil
# Expected behavior: to return false
# Actual behavior: updates my_enum and returns true
```

Repeat the same setup and check with bang bang `!!`, the column will be updated to `nil` as well.

```
!!@model # Updates my_enum to nil
# Expected behavior: to return true
# Actual behavior: updates my_enum to nil and returns false
# Note that @model being an instance should evaluate to true
```

This is the query executed after running `!@model` or `!!@model`

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "examples" SET "my_enum" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "examples"."id" = $3  [["my_enum", nil], ["updated_at", 2018-11-01 13:50:50 UTC], ["id", 1]]
   (2.8ms)  COMMIT
```

**Why is this happening?** Is it a bug solved in other rails version? Which would be the best workaround? Wouldn't you expect the same behavior as us? If it worked as expected we would ignore all empty strings, now we may need a `before_save: prevent_empty_in_my_enum`.

Possibly usefull information:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value('SELECT version()')
   (1.7ms)  SELECT version()
=> "PostgreSQL 9.5.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4, 64-bit"
```

Comment: It don't think doing `enum my_enum: { '': 0, good: 1}` is a good idea at all since the enum mappings are used to declare accessor, mutator and inquiry methods. I would handle the bad parameter (cast '' to nil) in the controller layer since it lets you eventually depreciate it in a later version of the api.

Comment: That may be the best approach as it leaves the model intact and prevents faults from spreading through the code. However, if having an empty string in our model was one of the requirements, we would face the same problem.

Comment: Thats a pretty strange requirement which kind of goes against what ActiveRecord::Enum is supposted to be used for. Your model can have a nil/undefined state - but what does an `''`  state actually mean?

Comment: @max remember the initial thought was to prevent it from going to the database `{'bad_param': nil, 'good': 1}` works as I would expect.

Comment: You can also achieve the same goal just by overriding the setter: `def my_enum=(val); super(val.blank? nil : val); end`.

Comment: That seems a good idea @max thanks. The question remains unsolved however and I would like other people that may encounter the same problem to find a solution, or in its defect, to add an issue to solve in future Rails versions.

Comment: I guessing the strange behaviour is due to the fact that ActiveRecord::Enum generates `!` and `?` methods when you use an empty string for the the key. However I don't really think this is a bug since it falls outside of the correct use. If anything ActiveRecord::Enum should raise an exception is the mapping key is blank.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think it's a bug, but if you think it's a problem or something that needs a solution then you should probably post this on activerecord's issues tracker or mailing list/google group to get to the real developers, it doesn't seem like a stackoverflow question.

Comment: @max I didn't remember a method `!` and `?` was defined for each enum. An empty string wouldnt have one of those methods. It makes perfect sense as you can't write `@model.?` Thanks! However why is it updating the column or why is no error raised?

Comment: Rails declares a mutator (good!) and and inquiry method (good?) on the model for each key in the mapping. If you use `define_method('?')` or `define_method('!')` you can actually create methods that are not syntactically allowed when you use `def`.  This is whats happing [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/21e5fd4a2a1c162ad33708d3e01b1fda165f204d/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L190).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct usage of `enum` is not intended for empty strings. Each enum key is converted to `def ?` and `def !` methods, so it does not make sense.

However, the silent column update may be a more important behavior. An [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34365) was submitted to the [Rails repo](https://github.com/rails/rails).

If it is not important enough to create a PR then the best solution is to find a workaround for this specific problem: prevent empty strings from being saved into the database.

The parameter could be filtered on the controller, allowing deprecation of that behavior in latter versions of the API.

Another option is to create a model method that prevents `blank?` parameters from being saved.

```
def my_enum=(value)
  super(value.blank? : nil, value)
end
```

This behavior is still the same in rails version `5.2.1`, as can be seen in the issue.

EDIT:

[The issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34365) was [fixed in PR#34385](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34385).